# Get data from post request in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to get the data after post request call, I have the following code in client side:

```
function (data) {
 console.log((data));
 const requestOptions = {
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
 sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") } };

 return $http.post("/api/Account/Filter", data, requestOptions);

            }
```

This is in server side:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Filter(Models.DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var employees = db.Users.OrderBy(ii => ii.Id).Select(x => new 
     RegisterBindingModel()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Email = x.Email,
            UserName = x.UserName,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            Age = x.Age,
            Phone = x.Phone,
            Department = x.Department
        });
        var i = employees.ToDataSourceResult(request.Take, request.Skip, request.Sort, request.Filter);
        var data = i.Data; // This is contain filtered data
        request.Take = i.Total;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Json(data));
        return Json(i.Data);
    }
```

How can I get the data to client side?

Comment: Check Request-Response-Handling in Javascript.

Comment: `return Ok(i.Data);`